# C# asp.net core inject DbContext without constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I try to create a BaseController and this should contain a DbContest instance.

```
public abstract class BaseODataController<T> : ODataController where T : class
{
    protected readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

    public BaseODataController(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }
}
```

So when i create a new controller, i have to pass the DbContext through the constructor.

Do i have the possibility to get a instance from the ApplicationDbContext like that:

```
    public BaseODataController()
    {
        _db = //Get instance?
    }
```

So i dont have to pass it in every controller?

Comment: @Set Not a duplicate, that other one has nothing to do with base classes.

Comment: What are you expecting then? What value would be assigned to `_db` and where would it come from??

Comment: @Flo sounds like you misunderstood what Inversion of Control and Dependency Injection are. *Instead* of hard-coding the creation of the DbContext inside your controller, thus making it very hard to customize and test, you *invert* this and *inject* that dependency in the constructor. That makes testing a lot easier eg by allowing you to pass a dummy or memory-only DbContext instead of the actual one. The DI container makes it easy to create a class with all of its dependencies

Comment: One of the option would be to use more advanced DI library and use property injection instead of constructor injection. This would allow you to leave you constructors parameterless. But I strongly don't recommend doing this because I believe your controllers will not work correctly with no `DbContext` so it's better pass this dependency in constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The ASP.NET Core dependency injection system will not resolve base class dependencies. You do need to explicitly provide that dependency to the base class from the constructors of your derived classes through the `base` statement:

```
public Foo(ApplicationDbContext db) : base(db)
{
    _db = db;
}
```

Comment: Of course, but i am lazy and would like to avoid this. :P

Comment: @Flo then you misunderstood how DI works. If the field is *protected* you don't have to store it anyway, just reference the base field

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos can a derived class ctor set a `readonly` field in the base class? I don't t hink I've tried that before, not sure if the one-time initialization rule carries over into the base class.

Comment: I know, but `readonly` means it can only be initialized by the constructor. What I'm wondering is whether that exception to "read-only" for the base class carries through to the derived class (given that derived classes can have different constructor signatures). That's not a visibility question.

Comment: Base constructors are *constructors*. You've probably already used this, especially with BCL classes and didn't realize it. In fact, it should be the *base* constructor that initializes base readonly fields, not derived classes. Otherwise you'd risk creating objects with invalid state. Which is a strong hint that the context should probably be a readonly *property* that prevents derived classes from messing with it

Comment: Still missing my point (and turning into more of an off-topic conversation than I'd intended), but I was considering a _derived_ constructor setting a _base_ read-only field. Took me less time to just build a quick test, and it does not work. Setting the `protected readonly` field in the base class from the derived constructor will not compile. (Ah, you were editing while I was posting. I agree with your conclusion.)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to set the field in your derived constructor, but you still must implement the constructor on the derived class. This has nothing to do with dependency injection; it's simply how inheritance works in C#. Constructors are not inherited, so if your want your derived class to have the same constructor available (which it will need, in order to accept the context), then it has to be declared on the derived class. However, you can simply pass the construction logic to the base constructor.

```
public abstract class BaseODataController<T> : ODataController
    where T : class
{
    protected readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

    public BaseODataController(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }
}

public class FooController : BaseODataController<Foo>
{
    public FooController(ApplicationDbContext context)
        : base(context)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes thats the way i currently do it

Comment: So what's the issue then? Are you just annoyed that you have to redeclare the constructor? Unfortunately, as I said, that's a language limitation, so you just have to suck it up.

Comment: Well, for what it's worth, in VS, you can simply right-click on the derived class name and there's an option there to implement each base constructor for you. At least then you don't have to type it ;)

Comment: Really? Haven't used VS for mac, but that's unfortunate. It's nice that they at least give an option for macs, but in general, the tooling will probably always be better on the windows side. Might be worth running bootcamp and real Visual Studio, depending on what you're primarily developing.

Answer (score -3):

You *could* store the dependency resolver in a static class and call it directly within the base class constructor, like e.g.:

```
_db = Container.Resolver.Resolve<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Comment: Incorrect syntax for ASP.NET Core's DI, and this is also the Service Locator anti-pattern ... and since they'd still have to use DI to get an instance of the DI `ServiceProvider` you don't really save any work this way.

Comment: Edited the answer to get the resolver into the controller and of course it's an anti pattern but it works.

Comment: That's the Service Locator *anti*pattern, the very thing DI is supposed to prevent.

Comment: @Nagelkopf but it doesn't. Not when you have to perform all this extra work to break the built-in mechanism.

Comment: I know but that answers the question and OP did not ask for a DI solution!